# Java Load all strings from file into a Set data structure with (key=string, value=line number)

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I've been trying to implement a `Set` data structure with key, value.
I have a `txt` file (EOL) have a String, line number something like this:

```
Adam,1
Mary,2
Michael,3
```

My goal is store this `key-value` inside a **Set**.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\musti\\Desktop\\demo.txt"));

    HashMap<String,Integer> mapFirstfile = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

        mapFirstfile.put(columns[0],Integer.parseInt(columns[1]));        }
    // HashMap sıralı yazdırmaz, LinkedHashSet sıralı tutar, ama ekstradan linkedlist lazım.
    System.out.println(mapFirstfile);
    System.out.println(mapFirstfile.keySet());
    System.out.println(mapFirstfile.values());

    Set<HashMap> setFirstfile = new HashSet<HashMap>();


}
```

Comment: What is the data structure of the object in the set supposed to be?

Comment: Could you add the code where you have tried to add your data to a Set please, it seems to be missing.

Comment: Hello Joakim, actually it is main problem, I though storing hashmap inside a set would be sensible but i am not pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer actually, but too long for comment...

First of all, `Set` is a structure of unique (in regards to `equals()`) values.

So your code above actually uses the correct structure `Map` where you map `String` to a number (`Integer`).

## Question 1

Is the number needed, is it in the file? You can calculate it from input

```
Adam
Mary
Michael
```

we know, that Adam is on a first line...

**edit 1:** You can use counter which you will increment every time you enter the loop. There is nothing in Java API to do that for you...

## Question 2

In your question, I'm missing information about what is not working... What is your expectation that is not true?

## Question 3

What in case of duplicates?

```
Alfa
Bravo
Alfa
```

Is it ok, that on the 3rd line you remap Alfa to 3?

## Question 4

What is your motivation to use `Set`?

As I wrote in `Set` contains "single" items. If your item contains several fields, you can wrap in in an `Object`, but I do not see the benefit...

Something like

```
class Item {
    String line;
    int lineNumber;
    // TODO: 1 add constructors
    // TODO: 2 add getter & setters
    // TODO: 3 implement equals() and hashCode()
}
```

and add it to `Set` like this:

```
Set mySet = ...
mySet.add(new Item(line, counter)); // you need to add such constructor
```

Comment: Question 1: Actually number is not needed but I couldn't figure it out how to get number line. If you can help me about that, i would be pleased. Question 2:  I'm seeking a way to store this key,value pair inside a Set data structure, there is no wrong code in my implementation. Question 3: I though with the help of the line number, i thought duplicate strings wouldn't be a problem. Am i wrong. Btw thank your interest

Comment: Hi Betlista, beyond the countering line, I need to attach the line and line number as I said, like a key, value. Because I'll compare two separate files and I will print mismatched strings. On the other hand, my assignment is about Set. I have to use it :)

Comment: @MustafaSakalli Part under Question 4 should help you to achieve what you need.